# How can I code a method for reuse when the critical parameter is a EF DbContext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, dbcontext, dry

I have 4 different SQL databases that hold similar data; they’re all based off the same model.  They differ according to version of the data, where they're being used, etc.

```
Db1Context
Db2Context
Db3Context
Db4Context
```

Upon initialization, I need to make sure each of the databases have a single parent record, so I run a method that looks something like this:

```
Sub EnsureATableExists()
  Dim theDb = New Db1Context
  Dim parentTable = theDb.parentTables.Where(Function(x) x.somedata = "somedata").FirstOrDefault()
  If parentTable Is Nothing Then
    parentTable = CreateTable()
    theDb.parentTables.Add(parentTable)
    theDb.SaveChanges()
  End If
End Sub
```

But I currently have 4 of these methods which offends my sense of DRY.  But I don’t how to write this method for reuse because the declaration of a DbContext is unique and I can’t really parametrize the DbContext to hand in.

I assume there is some common technique for coding this and would appreciate being taught.

**Additional code added per comment below:**

This is my current context.  It is repeated 3 more times with the different names like listed above and respective connection strings.

I converted my vb.net to C# and believe I'll be able to convert any examples provided back into vb.net.

```
public class Db1Context : DbContext
{
    public Db1Context() : base("Db1Connection")
    {
    }

    public Db1Context (string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Table1> Table1s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Table2> Table2s { get; set; }
}
```

How would I define a class to be inherited where I can define a new connection string, and what would the new Db1-Db4 contexts look like as they inherit?

Comment: make all your dbcontext classes inherit from the same class and use that class as the parameter to your method. i work with c# not vb or i'd give you a concrete example

Comment: That's OK.  I think I understand your point and will try to work that out and get back to you.  Might take a few days.  Thx.